# Dojo Build - basePath not working as expected

Tags: dojo

I was using the basePath property but the result of the build is not what I expected.
This is my profile based on one of the basic examples

```
dependencies= {
    basePath:"../..",
    releaseDir: "./TESTING"

};
```

I’m executing the build with the following command (shows the folder where the batch file is located and the full path to the profile)

```
C:\Users\me\Downloads\dojo-release-1.10.8-src\util\buildscripts>build.bat --profile "C:\Users\me\Downloads\dojo-release-1.10.8-src\util\buildscripts\profiles\test.profile.js" --release
```

According to the documentation
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/buildSystem.html#id1

> “If the profile contains the property basePath and the value of that
>   property is a relative path, then the build system will automatically
>   resolve that path with respect to the directory in which the profile
>   resources resides–not the current working directory”
>
> “Relative destination paths are computed with respect to the profile
>   property releaseDir, optionally with a concatenated path segment given
>   by profile property releaseName. If releaseDir is relative, then it is
>   taken to be relative to basePath”

So if I specify the basePath as I did, I would have expected it to place itself relative to the profile location that I specified, so that is

Profile location

> C:\Users\me\Downloads\dojo-release-1.10.8-src\util\buildscripts\profiles\test.profile.js

basePath location relative to profile (go back two levels)

> C:\Users\me\Downloads\dojo-release-1.10.8-src\util\

So going back two levels means placing myself in the ‘util’ folder
So I would expect the release dir to be written in the util folder as well.

However it is being written to the
buildscripts folder inside util.
On a second test I made the profile like this

```
dependencies= {
    basePath:"../..",
    releaseDir: "../TESTING"

};
```

And my release directory was written to the util folder. Which means the basePath I specified is actually pointing to the buildscripts folder but there is no subfolder deep enough to get to it using …/… if …/… means going back two levels.
So either I misunderstand what …/… means or something else is going on.
Can someone please explain how paths work in the build system when you specify a basePath?
Thanks